# Girar imagem 360º em 3D

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, 3d

Trabalho em uma empresa que vende máquinas e peças para engenhos que produzem o arroz, e estou desenvolvendo um sistema para venda de peças para essas máquinas... meu chefe quer que cada peça o cliente possa ver ela de vários angulos, ou seja, que ela faça um giro de 360º em 3D. Como exemplo ele me mandou esse video de uma empresa no qual fornecemos o mesmo maquinario. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDgDmfEhJ_M&t=28s   - em 1:16 aparece o que necessito)..

Alguem faz alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Se você tiver usando apenas PNG, JPEG etc, pode tentar o http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel

Comment: Tem um engenheiro mecanico na empresa, ele poderia refazer com os programinha que eles usam, ou fazer tipo um video também né? Mas esse que me mandou é ótimo, era algo assim que procurava